# How to return string and int variables in the same line as output in C#?

Tags: fonts, google-fonts

I tried to return an integer combined with some words in C#. (e.g., return "Your ID is ") + id1; but it didn't work. Is there a way to return multiple types of variables in C#?

`public int Test(int id1) { return "Your ID is " + id1; }`

Answer (score 1):

C# won't let you return a value with a different data type than the method's return type.

Maybe try something like:

```
public string Test(int id1) { return $"Your ID is {id1}"; }
```